# HTML form POST method not working (despite URL params showing)

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Got a form setup to submit some stuff.

There are three submit buttons, all with the same name (choice) and different IDs (1, 2 & 3).

Using POST method to submit the form to form.php

Form.php loads and I can see the form params in the URL.

However there is no POST data coming in.

**Index.php:**

```
<form action='form.php' action='POST'>

<input type='hidden' name='index' value='".$cell_count."'>

<div class='btn-group btn-group-m'>
  <button name='choice' value='1' type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-danger'>
    ...
  </button>

  <button name='choice' value='2' type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-warning'>
    ...
  </button>

  <button name='choice' value='3' type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-success'>
    ...
  </button>
</div>

<button name='choice' type='submit' value='4' class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>
  ...
</button>
```

**Form.php :**

```
<?php

  var_dump($_POST);

  if($_POST['choice'] == 3) {
    echo "Chose 3";
  }
  else if($_POST['choice'] == 2) {
    echo "Chose 2";
  }
  else if($_POST['choice'] == 1) {
    echo "Chose 1";
  }

 echo "index: " . $_POST['index'];

?>
```

**Result :**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrB7j.png 
Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Because you "can see the form params in the URL" tells me that this is a `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing the attributes:

```
<form action='form.php' action='POST'>
```

Should be:

```
<form action='form.php' method='POST'>
```

Now you don't have a `method` attribute, so the form is sent by GET (the default).

Answer (score 2):

You're form should be using `method="POST"`. The fact that you are seeing the parameters means that your form is submitting as `GET`.

The form code should be:

```
<form action='form.php' method='POST'>
```

Answer (score 1):

The action isn't supposed to be post, the METHOD is post.

```
<form action='form.php' method='post'>
```